# How to Get all total test case counts and status from project tear down script

Tags: groovy, soapui

Below is the tear down script to get the all test case counts and status from suite tear down but i need to get the overall test suite counts and status from project tear down but unfortunately it will not support the object of test runner class.

```
def failedTestCases = 0
runner.results.each { testCaseResult -> 
    def name = testCaseResult.testCase.name
    if(testCaseResult.status.toString() == 'FAILED') {
        failedTestCases++
        log.info "$name has failed"
        testCaseResult.results.each { testStepResults ->
            testStepResults.messages.each { msg -> log.info msg }
        }
     } else {
         log.info "$name works correctly"
     }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with the current script?

Comment: Current script is working from test suite tear down  but the same is not accessible from project tear down script( I need to get the test case count and status for all suites )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your project, create a Setup Script:

```
project.setPropertyValue("testcasesRun","0")
project.setPropertyValue("testcasesFailed","0")
```

On each of your TestSuites, create a TearDown Script something along this:

```
def failedTestCases = 0
def testCasesRun = 0
runner.results.each { testCaseResult -> 
    testCasesRun++
     if(testCaseResult.status == com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.Status.FAILED) {
        failedTestCases++
    }
}

def existingFailedTestCases = new Integer( runner.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("testcasesFailed") )
def newFailedValue = existingFailedTestCases + failedTestCases
runner.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("testcasesFailed",newFailedValue.toString())

def existingRunTestCases =  new Integer( runner.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("testcasesRun") )
def newRunTestCases = existingRunTestCases + testCasesRun
runner.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("testcasesRun",newRunTestCases.toString())
```

After running the project, you should have two Project Properties, holding number of counted testcases and failed testcases.

Comment: Really thanks a lot @steen, i have tried the approach which works fine , only little bit change require for tostring() conversion  before setting to the property.. {code}   def newFailedValue = (existingFailedTestCases + failedTestCases).toString()   runner.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("testcasesFailed",newFailedValue) {code} Accepting the answer happily.